# How can I take a working SPF and turn it into a SenderID?

Tags: spf

Our SPF settings are working fine, and we are signing up for Sailtrhu (a mailing list service provider) and they are insisting we set up SenderID. From what we've read, SenderID can conflict with SPF so we don't want to clobber our existing setup.

Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SenderID can be used to make assertions about both the envelope-sender ("`mfrom`") and the purported responsible-address ("`pra`"). SPF only makes assertions about the envelope-sender so the best approximation to an SPF like:

```
"v=spf1 a:1.2.3.4 ..."
```

...is a SenderID of:

```
"spf2.0/mfrom a:1.2.3.4 ..."
```

...with no `pra` section.